# Try in finally block

Tags: c#, try-finally

```
try
{
    operation1();
    operation2();
    ...
}
finally
{
    try
    {
        finalizer_operation1();
        finalizer_operation2();

    }
    finally
    {
        very_critical_finalizer_operation_which_should_occurs_at_the_end();
    }
}
```

Is this ok? To have finalizer as another `try/finally` block (because `finalizer_operationX()` may throw and I must ensure that `very_critical...()` will happens at the end.

Quick googling for *try in finally block* brings nothing (will delete question if you give me a duplicate link), it **should** work, but I am unsure in design and possible problems with it.

Comment: It should be ok, just keep in mind that finalize section is executed always, even if you have a return statement in catch section

Comment: I don't see any problem. For example, if you call some method from `finally` block, which, in turn, contains its own `try-finally` blocks - nothing special. In your case this happens in the same method.

Comment: @CosminMihai, I don't have `catch` section here ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would not write the code this way.  I don't like nesting try/catch/finally constructs.  I prefer one per method.

My preference is to wrap each of those calls in its own method.

```
try
{
    operation1();
    operation2();
    ...
}
finally
{
    cleanup();
}

public void cleanup() {
    try
    {
        finalizer_operation1();
        finalizer_operation2();

    }
    finally
    {
        very_critical_finalizer_operation_which_should_occurs_at_the_end();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd do that, but in my case operations and finalizer_operations are using same local variables (defined in first `try`), that's why moving code into a new method is problematic.

Comment: @Sinatr there's is this obscure concept of `method parameters`

Comment: @decPL, yes, but if things get changed, then I have to edit parameters, etc. I think passing parameters obscure control logic by alot more than `try/finally`. I do really like concept *guarantily executed at the end*, was simply not sure in nesting. I still remember `winapi` nightmare, when after each function call you check for return variable and restore what has already done before by successfully executed functions (sort of rollback). A lot of WET `if`s...

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is. A `finally` block *will* execute if control flow enters the corresponding `try` block.

The only exception is a call that shuts down the VM.

Comment: We don´t have A JVM here, just a VM :)

Comment: We'll publish jointly!

Comment: Still no `System.exit` :)

Comment: Sometimes less is more. I confess: I'm no C# programmer (never got the hang of the difference between a `struct` and a `class`) and thought this was a Java question. Checking if this answer is correct in C#...

Comment: Yup it holds. And I don't find the OP's style objectionable, particularly if you're attached to RAII features of other languages like C++.